# Order Confirmation Template Not Being Picked up

Tags: email-templates, render

I'm working on a store which language wise is set to use en_UK. Here - `app/locale/en_GB/template/email/sales` I added email templates. For some reason the order confirmation email template is being picked up for guests - `order_new_guest.html` but the `order_new.html` (for people that are logged in) is not.

To my knowledge `en_US` is the default folder so for testing purposes copied my changes to the `order_new.html` in here but it is still rendering a default file. Where else might default templates be stored? I can either copy my changes in here as a quick fix or even better if someone can think of a reason why it is not picking up this template I can try something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento overwrites these templates. You can overwrite them in the backend under

```
System > Configuration > Transactions mails
```

But I can't tell you how to see, whether this is already the case.